# How is calling a method from a class directly different from creating the class and calling the method?

Tags: java, memory

Is there a difference in the way they use memory, and  which cases should be considered when doing this? Here is an example of what I mean.

```java
// Calling a method directly
if(a) {
   new MyClass().method1();
} else if(b) {
   new MyClass().method2();
} else if(c) {
   new MyClass().method3();
}
```

Against the following

```java
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
if(a) {
   mc.method1();
} else if(b) {
   mc.method2();
} else if(c) {
   mc.method3();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a slight difference.

In the first case, the instance is scoped to each conditional block and eligible for garbage collection once the block ends - only one block will be executed.

In the second case, the instance is scoped to the outer block, and eligible for garbage collection once the outer block ends.

In either case, only one instance of that class is created, although given the lack of safetynet `else` case in the first example, you might end up with no instance created at all (thanks @Nexevis).

That does not, of course, include possible leaks or dependencies within the class' constructor, initializing blocks or method implementations - which is impossible to know with the given context.

Also there's no telling what the outer block does, e.g. returning that instance to the caller, etc.

Comment: A very small nitpick but in the first case, there is a possibility on _no_ instance being created since there is no `else`.